# gluster operations hangs when one node fail

Tags: mount, high-availability, glusterfs

I have 3 nodes gluster server. Most of mounts from it are readonly and are to localhost like:

```
mount -t glusterfs localhost:/volume /mnt/mountpoint/ -o ro
```

volume is type replicate with 3 replicas (one brick on every node)

I've configured for volume options like:

```
cluster.quorum-count: 1
cluster.quorum-type: fixed
cluster.server-quorum-type: none
```

I would expect that fail/reboot of one node doesn't interrupt read operations from localy mounted volume. Unfortunally - when i reboot any node or any node is fail - even read operations like

```
ls -l /mnt/mountpoint/somefile
```

hangs until failed node is up or network.ping-timeout is reached.
I've tried versions up to current 3.8.

Is there any way to configure glusterfs to serve (local!) content always, independent from failed nodes?

Answer (score 3):

If someone is still looking for an answwer...

GlusterFS has a default timeout of 42 seconds. You can execute this command:

`gluster volume set VOLUME_NAME network.ping-timeout 5`

Where 5 is the amount of seconds you want your gluster to hang before becoming operational again. You only have to set this option on one of the nodes as it is a shared option.